# iOS 8: -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] not calling delegate

Tags: cllocationmanager, ios8

I'm calling -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] on the main thread. I've set my delegate, and I supplied a value in info.plist for the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key.

The dialog asking the user for access shows appropriately, but when the user taps "Allow" or "Disallow", the delegate method -[locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] isn't being called.

I'm on iOS 8, so it could be a bug...but it seems like too big a bug to go unnoticed. Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: i have found that this problem occurs only when the app has been recently installed for the first time. if you delete the app then reinstall it, the problem doesn't happen. it's easy to reproduce this on a simulator. click "Reset content and settings" in the simulator menu, then install your app. the problem will occur. then delete the app and reinstall it. the problem will not occur. i have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a strong reference to the CLLocationManager object. I was having a similar issue and I realized that I never created a property for it.

Comment: I don't know that this was my problem, but it is indeed a problem to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was doing this

CLLocationManager* lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[lm requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

and having the dialog box flash up and dissapear again

Answer (score 0):

The code works now...I am, for the moment, going to assume that it was a bug in iOS 8 betas.